# In Django how are user request objects attached to views?

Tags: django

When a Django application receives a http request from a browser, what function is responsible for calling a view?
Does that function first manipulate the Http request information before calling the view function?
Does the function also perform automatic user retrieval like in:

The user object is available on the request object

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
    # ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.user` is attached by [`AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dd9cd7923ed62a53e101ce2c3caea37e24d66c0a/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L15-L23).

Middleware and your view function gets called by [`BaseHandler.get_response()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dd9cd7923ed62a53e101ce2c3caea37e24d66c0a/django/core/handlers/base.py#L71-L83).

Answer (score -1):

When you create a view function you create a request object that is linked to the view we have two type of request "Post", post if you submit data to the server and "get"and you want to read information from the server
below there is an example

```
enter code here def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login')
        return redirect('login')
enter code here
```

This function is called when a user register a from and submit then the function will redirect him to the login view that will take his newly created credentials.

Comment: "when you create a view function you create a request" is wrong. And this doesn't answer the question.